# Objective-C init quirks

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, initializer, autorelease

In a class interface I define some ivar

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) id < Protocol > initEst;   // Initial estimate
```

This compiles without a problem but when I run the program it crashes with **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** and **[Object .cxx_destruct]** indicated by the debugger as the reason.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this some more and there seems to be **three** conditions for this particular quirk to show up.

In my particular case the ivar's `Protocol` was also the same as that of the containing class. This seems to be an additional requirement for this problem to surface (refering here to my earlier answer that did not mention this).

So to elaborate on my earlier answer. If

1. `initXXX` is an ivar
2. of `id` type
3. that implements a `Protocol` that is the **same** as the containing class

then the Objective-C + ARC compiler will happily compile the code but be unable to execute it.

Here is a sample of the code I used to test

```
@interface Dog : NSObject < Animal >

@property (nonatomic,strong) id < Animal > initState;

@end
```

Something like this will cause problems simply because the name starts with **init**. Change the name and all problems disappear.

For reference, the runtime error this generates is

> Dog object overreleased while already deallocating

This snippet is pretty abstract but this may bite you in places where you need to specify some initial condition and where it is natural to name some ivar `initXxx` but beware, if you use Objective-C you do not have that luxury nor will the compiler warn you that it is wrong.

The original error seemed memory allocation related and caused me to suspect the way I used the **autoreleasepool** but now I am fairly convinced this has nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the rules of ARC automatic memory management. An initializer has special rules for how it treats the returned value: it retains and returns. See https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#semantics-of-init.

Objective-C in general, and ARC in particular, have some pretty strict rules about what names of methods mean. `initXXX` means "this is an initializer". If this isn't an initializer, don't use the `init` prefix.

You could turn off ARC entirely and manage memory yourself, but it's easier just to obey the conventions, and it fits better in case of interaction with other languages (such as Swift).

Comment: I accept the trouble with `init` but even the link ties `init` only to methods. I was not using a method at all and was surprised that it was treated as such.

Comment: If I did not use ARC I could just retain and autorelease it. I want to know specifically how ARC and autoreleasepool work together when you allocate inside and use outside the autorelease.

Comment: @skaak `self.initEst = ...` is identical to `[self setInitEst:...]`.

Comment: If `initEst` points to a normal object the compiler will complain about the `init` part but if it is an `id` pointer then it will not complain, so you can only do `self.initEst =` or `[self setInitEst:...]` if it is an `id` pointer.